# Why does FFT size equals the numbers of samples in the time domain?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

My question is simple. I think I kind of understand FFT and DFT. what I dont understand is why, in Python or matlab, do we use FFT size as the number of samples? why does every sample taken in the time domain corresponds to a frequency bin in the frequency domain.

For example the Scipy's fft pack, in order to plot the spectrum of a `.wav` file signal we use:

```
FFT = abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(time_domain_signal));
Frequency_Vector = fftpack.fftfreq(len(FFT_out), (1/Sampling_rate))
```

Now if I type the `len(FFT_out)`

it is the the same as the number of samples (ie sampling freq * time of the audio signal) and since ffreq is the frequency vector that contains the frequency bins, therefore Len(fft) = number of frequency bins.

A simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What FFT function are you talking about ? I guess it comes from a package, but which one ? What do you call FFT size ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a [specific programming problem or any other topic suitable for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @JosephBudin I am talking about Scipy's fft pack, in order to plot the spectrum of a wav. file signal we use FFT = abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(time_domain_signal))
Frequency_Vector = fftpack.fftfreq(len(FFT_out), (1/Sampling_rate))

Now if I type the len(FFT_out) it is the the same as the number of samples (i:e sampling freq * time of the audio signal)

and since ffreq is the frequency vector that contains the frequency bins, therefore Len(fft) = number of frequency bins

Comment: @ftkhateeb, you should aboslutely include that comment in your question before it gets closed. Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically a key property of the fourier transform is that it is linear and invertible. The latter means that if two signals have the same fourier transform they are equal, and that for any spectrum there is a signal with that spectrum.

For implementations with a finite collection of samples of a signal the first property means that the fourier tramsform can be represented by a N x M matrix where N is the number of time samples and M the number of frequency samples. The second property means that the matrix must be invertible, and so square, ie we must have M == N.

You say that time bins and frequency correspond, and that is true in the sense that there are the same number of them. However the value in each frequency bin will depend on all time values.